# What is the significance of Constant Pool (Symbolic or Logical References) in Java?

Tags: java, jvm

I want to ask, why we need logical references instead we have references to the memory location physically?

Comment: @vatsalmevada : Nope

Comment: If you think, your question is different, you have to write more than just “Nope”. Perhaps it helps explaining what your “logical references” are supposed to be and how you think they differ from “references to the memory location physically”…